# How to implement clickable info-bubble on tap of marker in HERE maps in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I have integrated HERE maps successfully in my iOS app, but now I am facing an issue in implementing info-bubble on tap of markers on HERE map.I have searched on HERE documentation for iOS SDK, but can't find anything relevant. There are many solutions for JS, but nothing for iOS.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't seem to exist on iOS and Android. In order to create a similar behaviour in iOS, you should use `NMAMapOverlay` instead and add your own subviews/styling to it.

The iOS SDK documentation states that `NMAMapOverlay can be used to display custom UIView-based content at a fixed location on the map. (...) Then, give the overlay a NMAGeoCoordinates location and add it to a map. The overlay will automatically be repositioned on the screen as the map moves.`

You can find more information about the best practices for the implementation here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.15/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapOverlay.html